# Using babeljs compiled files with existing project

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a simple class that is written in ES6

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.firstVar = 'a';
    this.secondVar = 'b';
  }
  get first() { return this.firstVar; }
  set first(val) { this.firstVar = val; }

  get second() { return this.secondVar; }
  set second(val) { this.secondVar = val; }

  allValues() {
    return this.firstVar + this.secondVar;
  }
}

export { MyClass };
```

I compile that code to ES5 via `babel MyClass.es6 > MyClass.js` and then try to use it in my existing ES5 codebase:

```
var t = require('./MyClass');
console.log(t.allValues());
```

But I get an error stating that t has no method allValues. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: *"Is what I'm trying to do possible?"* What *are* you trying to do? Classes have to be instantiated. You are never creating an instance of `MyClass`. You are also importing it incorrectly. In it's current form, you would have to do `var MyClass = require('./MyClass').MyClass; var t = new MyClass(); console.log(t.allValues());`.

Comment: If you change this to an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: [@nathasm](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1392862/nathasm) Just to clarify. Are you using the new `ES5` compiled code in your `ES5` with or without the `Babel` library?

Comment: Without I guess? I was just going to compile down to ES5 and then use the files as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes have to be instantiated. You are never creating an instance of `MyClass`. You are also importing it incorrectly. You are exporting `MyClass` as a *named export* and have to import it as such.

In its current form, you would have to do

```
var MyClass = require('./MyClass').MyClass;
var t = new MyClass();
console.log(t.allValues());
```

Or you can export it as default export:

```
export default MyClass;
```

In which case you can do

```
var t = require('./MyClass');
```

(at least with Babel)

Comment: You were right, I missed the wrapping of `exports` with his object `{ MyClass }`

Comment: [Felix](http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) Where I was going with my answer was that I thought the OP was using `Babel` to create `ES5` compiled code and inject it directly into his old projects without using the `Babel` library.  If he wasn't, my bad.